# How to check file extension looping through an array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, foreach, file-extension, multiple-file-upload

test-data component.ts

```
export class TestDataManagementComponent {
requirement = [] as any;
testDataFileType = "doc,docx,xls,xlsx,pdf,application/msword,application/msexcel,application/pdf";
isNotAccepted = false;

submitForm() {
var splitted = this.testDataFileType.split(",");
let payload = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < this.requirement.length; i++) {
      payload.append('requirements', this.requirement[i]);
    }

splitted.forEach(function (value) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < this.requirement.length; i++) {
    if(this.requirement[i].name.split('.').pop() === value) {
      this.isNotAccepted = false;
      break;
    } 
    if(this.requirement[i].name.split('.').pop() !== value) {
      this.isNotAccepted = true;
      break;
}
}
});
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'requirement' of undefined

Please help me figure out why 'requirement' is not defined and what is the best way to check each file's extension looping through the type array at once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is related to the reference of `this`.
`this` in JS is very confusing and one needs to be very cautious while writing the code.
Here is the problem :

```
splitted.forEach(function (value) {
  for(let i = 0 ; i < this.requirement.length; i++) {
..... rest of the code 
}
```

You assume that in the class, `this` will refer to object/class.  Well, it actually doesn’t. `this` is not defined to refer to the object that encloses it when you write your code.
Instead, this refers to `whoever called the code in which it’s being used`.
So Either you need to explicitly bind `this` to the method or use `arrow` function (which by default has class reference of `this`).

for example :

```
 splitted.forEach(value => {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.requirement.length; i++) {
        if (this.requirement[i].name.split(".").pop() === value) {
          this.isNotAccepted = false;
          break;
        }
        if (this.requirement[i].name.split(".").pop() !== value) {
          this.isNotAccepted = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      
    });
```

Here is a good read : [MDN : this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
working example : [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-btcusc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)